# Using grep -q in shell one-liners

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I've written a script to list commits in a repo that contain a specific file. It's working perfectly, but I don't understand why I had to write this:

```
for c in $(git rev-list "$rev_list"); do
    git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Saw $file in $c"
    fi
done
```

Whereas I normally write the same thing like this:

```
[[ $(git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file") ]] && echo "Saw $file in $c"
# or
[[ ! $(git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file") ]] || echo "Saw $file in $c"
```

Neither of the short versions work: they don't output anything. When I write it so that it shows all commits that don't contain the file, I do get output:

```
[[ $(git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file") ]] || echo "Did not see $file in $c"
```

However, if I then take a commit hash from the output and run

```
git ls-tree -r <the hash> | grep file
```

I notice the file **is** in the tree for some commits, leading me to believe it's just listing all the commits the script processes. Either way, I'm probably missing something, but I can't exactly work out what it is

Comment: Try: `git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file" && echo "Saw $file in $c" || echo "nope"`

Comment: If you normally write any of those then, as l0b0, indicated in their answer you have been doing it wrong all this time. Seeing as how those cannot possibly ever work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the command in a conditional statement (`[[ $(command) ]]`). In fact, that will never work with `grep -q`, because you're actually testing whether the command *prints* anything. You can just do this:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | grep -q "$file" && echo "Saw $file in $c"
```

In general, any code block like

```
foreground_command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    bar
fi
```

can be replaced with either

```
if foreground_command
then
    bar
fi
```

or even

```
foreground_command && bar
```

Which of the three alternatives you should use depends on whether `foreground_command`, `bar`, or both are multi-line commands.

Comment: I can't believe I was that stupid... I basically missed the `-q` in the grep command. I could punch myself now :)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r "$c" | awk "/$file/{printf '%s in %s\n', '$file', '$c'}"
```