# Using grep in an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, grep

My goal is to write a shell script take the users that I have already filtered out of a file and check whether those users have a certain string, and if they do, label them as major, if not, nonmajor. My trouble is coming from my first if statement, and I'm not sure if grep is the right way to go in an if statement. Here is what I have:

```
(
while read i
do


username=`echo $i | grep -v 'CMPSC 1513' | grep -P -v '(?!.*CPSMA 2923)CPSMA' | cut -d'|' -f2` 
fullname=`echo $i | grep -v 'CMPSC 1513' | grep -P -v '(?!.*CPSMA 2923)CPSMA' | cut -d'|' -f3`
id=`echo $i | grep -v 'CMPSC 1513' | grep -P -v '(?!.*CPSMA 2923)CPSMA' | cut -d'|' -f4`

if [ $username ]
then

if grep -q "|0510"
then 
    echo $username":(password):(UID):(GID):"$fullname"+"$id":/home/STUDENTS/majors:/bin/bash"
else 
    echo $username":(password):(UID):(GID):"$fullname"+"$id":/home/STUDENTS/nonmajors:/bin/bash"
fi      
fi

done
)<./cs_roster.txt
```

Just some info, this is contained in a while loop. In the while loop, i determine whether the person listed should even be major or nonmajor, and my if [ $username ] has been tested and does return all the correct users. At this point the while loop is only running once and then stopping.

Comment: Added. Sorry about that.

Comment: John Kugelman, as explained in the post, dropping the brackets only returns first user and not all matches. Do you know the cause for this?

Comment: Hi Cassidy and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have problems with scripts, then you might always try to parse it with https://www.shellcheck.net/. When I used it on your example, it detected the problem and indicated how you could solve it.

Comment: Also, please post a complete example that allows other users to reproduce your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Another pointer for you: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control. The `-q` switch enables exactly the behavior you list as problematic: stops at the first match.

Comment: Use double quoted around variables.  Test explicitly for empty (`-z`) or non-empty (`-n`) strings: `if [ -n "$username" ]`.  Don't use `[` before a command you want executed: `if grep -q '|510' …file…; then …; else …; fi`.

Comment: What does your input file look like? All those calls to `grep` are almost certainly unnecessary. What is the input for the `if` statement's `grep` supposed to be? Currently, it's going to read the rest of `cs_roster`; did you mean `echo "$i" | grep -q "|0510"` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep -q in shell one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923962/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the square brackets and pass `$i` to `grep`:

```
if echo $i | grep -q "|0510"
```

In your code sample, `grep` does not have anything to work on.

Comment: I think you should clarify the question. What is your goal? How does the data look like?

Comment: You might need to use a regular expression to catch both the `|0510` magic string and the username, maybe `"$username.*|0510`". Not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: Ok, I see the error maybe. You are not passing anything to grep besides the `-q` switch and the string to grep.

Comment: It would help if we wouldn't need to guess how the rest of the code looks like, and if you posted a complete example that allows people to help you, instead of having to try to infer the structure of the rest of the code from your description.

Comment: You are not including all of the relevant code, either.  You don't have the while loop you mentioned and you are only getting the first result.  THAT is your problem.  The brackets need to go away because that's a boolean test.  `[` is a program.  It returns an exit status.  `if` only cares about the exit status of the program that follows it.  `[` does not take `grep` for an argument.  It takes tests for equality.

Comment: `[` is not an operator.  This may seem like a pedantic point, but it really is the core cause of the confusion.  It is a command, just like `grep`

Comment: Your edited answer solved my problem thank you so much.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer if it's a solution to your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "binary operator expected" occurs because you are invoking the command `[` with the arguments "grep" and "-q"  (you are not invoking grep at all), and `[` expects a binary operator where you have specified `-q`.  `[` is a command, treated no differently that `grep` or `ls` or `cat`.  It is better (IMO) to spell it `test`, and when invoked by the name `test` it does not require that its last argument be `]`.  If you want to use `grep` in an if statement, just do something like:

```
if echo "$username" | grep -q "|0510"; then ...
```

(Although I suspect, depending on the context, there are better ways to accomplish your goal.)

The basic syntax of an if statement is `if pipeline; then...`.  In the common case, the pipeline is the simple command `test`, and at some point in pre-history, the decision was made to provide the name `[` for the `test` command with the added caveat that its final argument must be `]`.  I believe this was done in an effort to make if statements look more natural, as if the `[` is an operator in the language.  Just ignore `[` and always use `test` and much confusion will be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did understand the test command and that the brackets ran the test command when I posted, but the original code is just what I had. I tried your solution and it echoed all being nonmajor when only one should be and the rest should be major. I edited my post to include my full code without brackets if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: That's a bad edit.  `if grep -q "|0510"` is reading from ./cs_roster.txt, and consuming data meant for the read in the condition of the while loop

Comment: I strongly suggest you look for an `awk` solution rather than trying to do this in a while loop.

Comment: The answer by Andrea solved my problem but thank you for the explanation of everything. Sorry if I may have been confusing. New to Stack Overflow and still trying to figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as an exercise. Write an `awk` script for it, or start with something like

```
while IFS='|' read -r f1 username fullname id otherfields; do
   # I don't know which field you want to test. I will rest with id
   if [[ $id =~ ^0510 ]]; then
      subdir=majors
   else
      subdir=nonmajors
   fi
   echo "${username}:(password):(UID):(GID):${fullname}+${id}:/home/STUDENTS/${subdir}:/bin/bash"
done < <( grep -v 'CMPSC 1513' ./cs_roster.txt | grep -P -v '(?!.*CPSMA 2923)CPSMA' )
```

This is nice for learning some bash syntax, but consider an `awk` script for avoiding a while-loop.